# How to get the Current activitiName in Alfresco Process services (Activti 7)

Tags: alfresco, activiti

In Alfresco APS 2.3 version, we have one upgrade i.e., Changing ActivitiExecution class to Delegate Execution class.

Both the classes has execute() method.

Inside the execute() method of ActivitiExecution, we have method called "getCurrentActivitiName()"

But inside the execute() method of DelegateExecution,we don't have this method called "getCurrentActivitiName()".

How to get the Current activitiName in Alfresco Process services (Activti 7)without this method in DelegateExecution class?

Answer (score 0):

Try by casting this way.

ActivityExecution activityExecution =(ActivityExecution) delegateExecution;